# In Ember.js, how to use parent model's functions

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models:

```
Parent = Ember.Model.extend({
  hello: function() {
    console.log("parent says hello");
  },
  world: function() {
    console.log("parent says world");
  }
});
Child = Ember.Model.extend(Parent, {
  hello: function() {
    console.log("child says hello");
    // how do I call Parent.hello here?
    // how do I call Parent.world here?
  }
});
```

I want to call the Parent.hello and Parent.world functions from within the Child.hello function.

How would I go about doing this? Is there a super method I can use or do I just use bind and reference the Parent model class within the Child.hello function?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this._super()` to call the parent method. It's talked about briefly in the Ember guides.

http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/

To call a method that hasn't been overridden you simple do `this.world()`.

You can see a sample of it here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/renijuqoko/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question, I want to grab the model that I'm inheriting from and access its attributes. Basically casting my sub-class into the parent class.

Comment: To be honest it answered your original question which just said call `Parent.hello` from `Child.hello` :) Anyway, methods that aren't overridden should be callable by just `this.world()`. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/renijuqoko/1/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 3):

Nothing fancy, just:

> how do I call Parent.hello here?

`this._super()`

> how do I call Parent.world here?

`this.world()`

[Working demo.](https://ember-twiddle.com/caae6920e6600dfa90c5)

Comment: what about if my Child also overrides the `world` attribute and I can no longer do this.world?

Comment: You can still call `this.super()` from child which overrides `world` in `world` method, so you still can do `this.world`, but from another method. It's just design. Seems like you really want to cast your instance to it's parent type, but it's not C#. :D